# How to prevent Visual Studio from reporting an caught exception?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, report

In this piece of code (runs in a unit test under debugging)

```cs
try
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessID);

    _isRunningCache = WindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero
                 && User32.IsWindow(WindowHandle) && !process.HasExited
                 && process.Responding;
}
catch
{
    return Invalidate();
}
```

I receive a report for an exception occurred (I do have reporting of unhandled exceptions enabled), but nevertheless visual studio interrupts the process and reports the exeption in the following manner:
[image: visual studio exception report]

What can I do to prevent this? (despite disabling reporting of unhandled exceptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Debug -> Exceptions and deselect any checkboxes in the 'Thrown' column.

Ensure the 'User-unhandled' is checked for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Comment: a now I understand that dialogue, so basically "Thrown" will break in any case? , thanks so much!